# Heisenbug Error in Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, race-condition

I call this Heisenbug error because the error only exists if it's not observed. Here is the call :

```
@selected_members  = Member.where(id: params[:member_ids])
@existing_members  = list.members
@new_members       = @selected_members.where('id not in (?)', @existing_members.map(&:id))
@members_to_lose   = @existing_members.where('enterprise_members.id not in (?)', @selected_members.map(&:id))

Rails.logger.info @members_to_lose.length # Remove this line and it no longer works
list.members       = @selected_members

render json: {members_to_add: @new_members, members_to_lose: @members_to_lose}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary whatsoever.

If I remove the `Rails.logger.info` call, then `@members_to_lose` returns incorrectly ( as in it returns blank ).

If I place the Logger or the Debugger *after* the `list.members = @selected_members` line, *then* the `@members_to_lose` is emptied, and returns incorrectly ( as in it returns blank ).

If instead of a `Rails.logger.info`, I just place a `debugger` before the `list.members` line, then it will return correctly.

What is happening here? Is this a ruby race condition? I have *nothing* in my code that would affect this code whatsoever. `List.members` is a simple `has_many` relationship.

Comment: Put in some extra logging looking at the class of `@members_to_lose`, and inspecting the object itself, before and after the `Rails.logger.info @members_to_lose.length` line.  I have a suspicion that the length call is changing it from a query chain into an array.

Comment: I think you mean *Heisenberg* rather than Schroedinger - http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html

Comment: Change `members_to_lose: @members_to_lose` to `members_to_lose: @members_to_lose.all`. The latter will execute the query against the database. `@new_members` require the same modification as well.

Comment: @Jon Noted, and edited. Thanks~

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: @mudasobwa `.all` only forces execution prior to rails 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails queries are lazily evaluated - they are executed the moment you actually need them.

```
Rails.logger.info @members_to_lose.length
```

This triggers the query because you call the method length.
When you skip this line the query gets executed at:

```
render json: {members_to_add: @new_members, members_to_lose: @members_to_lose}
```

At this point you have saved the new members.

To execute the query add load:

```
@members_to_lose   = @existing_members.where('enterprise_members.id not in (?)', @selected_members.map(&:id)).load
```

I'd also recommend using select instead of map for better performance:

```
@members_to_lose   = @existing_members.where('enterprise_members.id not in (?)', @selected_members.select('enterprise_members.id')).load
```

Comment: That's it. You nailed. Wow. Thanks so much. I've never heard of `load` before. Fascinating.

Comment: `pluck` is even better than `select` performance wise (select still instantiates full AR objects)

Comment: When you use select in a query there are no objects instantiated. Active record generates one query with a subquery: select .. where id in (select id from ..). With pluck however we have 1 extra query for getting the ids and an array instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `where` is lazy loading the data.

When you do, `Rails.logger.info @members_to_lose.length` it basically loads the data.

If you dont do that and trigger the last line, it is basically copying the object without actually evaluating it. Thus you are not getting anything in the result.